# Checkbox is throwing an error in a PHP form

Tags: php, ajax, forms, checkbox

I've got a script that I downloaded that's a contact form with reCaptcha v3 which emails the filled out form.

The reCaptcha and mail is working, but am having a problem with the checkboxes.

When I fill out the form, my error log says

```
PHP Warning:  Undefined variable $instype in /home1/bluehqwi/public_html/gowithfm/quote/AjaxForm.php on line 121
```

The code at line 121 is:

```
'instype[]' => $instype
```

This is what I have in the AjaxForm.php for checkboxes -

```
if(!empty($_POST['instype[]'])) {
    foreach($_POST['instype[]'] as $instype){
        echo "value : ".$instype.'<br/>';
    }
}
```

In my form, my checkboxes are -

```
<input class="form-check-input shadow-none" type="checkbox" value="Business insurance" name="instype[]" id="instype">
<label class="form-check-label" for="instype">Business insurance</label>

<input class="form-check-input shadow-none" type="checkbox" value="Life insurance" name="instype[]" id="instype">
<label class="form-check-label" for="instype">Life insurance</label>
```

I need to have multiple checkboxes in the contact form and have those displayed in the email that's sent.

I'm more on the UX/UI Design side, so I'm not really fluent in Ajax and PHP, so any help is appreciated.

Thanks!

**NOTE:** *Here's the complete AjaxForm.php file.*

```
<?php

/**
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer;
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\Exception;
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\SMTP;

# https://www.php.net/manual/fr/timezones.php
date_default_timezone_set('America/Los_Angeles');

require __DIR__ . '/../PHPMailer/Exception.php';
require __DIR__ . '/../PHPMailer/PHPMailer.php';
require __DIR__ . '/../PHPMailer/SMTP.php';
require __DIR__ . '/../recaptcha/autoload.php';

class Ajax_Form {

    # Constants to redefined
    # Check this for more configurations: https://blog.mailtrap.io/phpmailer
    const HOST        = 'xxxxx'; # SMTP server
    const USERNAME    = 'xxxxx'; # SMTP username
    const PASSWORD    = 'xxxxx'; # SMTP password
    const SECRET_KEY  = 'xxxxx'; # GOOGLE secret key
    const SMTP_SECURE = PHPMailer::ENCRYPTION_STARTTLS;
    const SMTP_AUTH   = true;
    const PORT        = 587;
    const SUBJECT     = 'xxxxx';
    const HANDLER_MSG = [
        'success'       => '✔️ Your message has been sent !',
        'token-error'   => '❌ Error recaptcha token.',
        'enter_firstname'    => '❌ Please enter your first name.',
        'enter_lastname'    => '❌ Please enter your last name.',
        'enter_email'   => '❌ Please enter a valid email.',
        'enter_phone' => '❌ Please enter a valid phone number.',
        'enter_message' => '❌ Please enter your message.',
        'enter_instype' => '❌ Please enter instype.',
        'bad_ip'        => '❌ 56k ?',
        'ajax_only'     => '❌ Asynchronous anonymous.',
        'email_body'    => '
            <h1>{{subject}}</h1>
            <p><b>First name:</b> {{firstname}}</p>
            <p><b>Last name:</b> {{lastname}}</p>
            <p><b>Email:</b> {{email}}</p>
            <p><b>Phone:</b> {{phone}}</p>
            <p><b>Address 1:</b> {{address1}}</p>
            <p><b>Address 2:</b> {{address2}}</p>
            <p><b>City:</b> {{city}}</p>
            <p><b>State:</b> {{state}}</p>
            <p><b>Zip:</b> {{zip}}</p>
            <p><b>Interested in:</b> {{instype}}</p>
'
    ];
            
            /* <p><b>Date</b>: {{date}}</p>
            <p><b>Name</b>: {{name}}</p>
            <p><b>E-Mail</b>: {{email}}</p>
            <p><b>Message</b>: {{message}}</p>
            <p><b>IP</b>: {{ip}}</p>
        ' 
    ];*/

    /**
     * Ajax_Form constructor
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        # Check if request is Ajax request
        if (!empty($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) && $_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH'] !== 'XMLHttpRequest') {
            $this->statusHandler('ajax_only');
        }

        # Check if fields has been entered and valid
        if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'POST') {
            $firstname    = $this->secure($_POST['firstname']) ?? $this->statusHandler('enter_name');
            $lastname    = $this->secure($_POST['firstname']) ?? $this->statusHandler('enter_name');
            $email   = filter_var($this->secure($_POST['email']), FILTER_SANITIZE_EMAIL) ?? $this->statusHandler('enter_email');
            $phone = $this->secure($_POST['phone']) ?? $this->statusHandler('enter_phone');
            $address1 = $this->secure($_POST['address1']) ?? $this->statusHandler('enter_address1');
            $address2 = $this->secure($_POST['address2']) ?? $this->statusHandler('enter_address2');
            $city = $this->secure($_POST['city']) ?? $this->statusHandler('enter_city');
            $state = $this->secure($_POST['state']) ?? $this->statusHandler('enter_state');
            $zip = $this->secure($_POST['zip']) ?? $this->statusHandler('enter_zip');
            # if (!empty($_POST['instype']))
            # $instype = $this->secure($_POST['instype']);
            # else
            # $this->statusHandler('enter_instype');
            if(!empty($_POST['instype'])) {
                foreach($_POST['instype'] as $instype){
                    echo "value : ".$instype.'<br/>';
                }
            }
            # $message = $this->secure($_POST['message']) ?? $this->statusHandler('enter_message');
            $token   = $this->secure($_POST['recaptcha-token']) ?? $this->statusHandler('token-error');
            $ip      = filter_var($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'], FILTER_VALIDATE_IP) ?? $this->statusHandler('bad_ip');
            $date    = new DateTime();
        }

        # Prepare email body
        $email_body = self::HANDLER_MSG['email_body'];
        $email_body = $this->template($email_body, [
            'subject' => self::SUBJECT,
            'date'    => $date->format('j/m/Y H:i:s'),
            'firstname' => $firstname,
            'lastname' => $lastname,
            'email' => $email,
            'phone' => $phone,
            'address1' => $address1,
            'address2' => $address2,
            'city' => $city,
            'state' => $state,
            'zip' => $zip,
            'instype' => $instype
        ]);

        # Verifying the user's response
        $recaptcha = new \ReCaptcha\ReCaptcha(self::SECRET_KEY);
        $resp = $recaptcha
            ->setExpectedHostname($_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'])
            ->verify($token, $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']);
            
        if ($resp->isSuccess()) {
            # Instanciation of PHPMailer
            $mail = new PHPMailer(true);
            $mail->setLanguage('en', __DIR__ . '/vendor/PHPMailer/language/');

            try {
                # Server settings
                $mail->SMTPDebug  = SMTP::DEBUG_OFF;   # Enable verbose debug output
                $mail->isSMTP();                       # Set mailer to use SMTP
                $mail->Host       = self::HOST;        # Specify main and backup SMTP servers
                $mail->SMTPAuth   = self::SMTP_AUTH;   # Enable SMTP authentication
                $mail->Username   = self::USERNAME;    # SMTP username
                $mail->Password   = self::PASSWORD;    # SMTP password
                $mail->SMTPSecure = self::SMTP_SECURE; # Enable TLS encryption, `ssl` also accepted
                $mail->Port       = self::PORT;        # TCP port

                # Recipients
                $mail->setFrom(self::USERNAME, $firstname, $lastname);
                $mail->addAddress($email, $firstname, $lastname);
                $mail->AddCC(self::USERNAME, 'Dev_copy');
                $mail->addReplyTo(self::USERNAME, 'Information');

                # Content
                $mail->isHTML(true);
                $mail->CharSet = 'UTF-8';
                $mail->Subject = self::SUBJECT;
                $mail->Body    = $email_body;
                $mail->AltBody = strip_tags($email_body);

                # Send email
                $mail->send();
                $this->statusHandler('success');

            } catch (Exception $e) {
                die(json_encode($mail->ErrorInfo));
            }
        } else {
            die(json_encode($resp->getErrorCodes()));
        }
    }

    /**
     * Template string values
     *
     * @param string $string
     * @param array $vars
     * @return string
     */
    public function template(string $string, array $vars): string
    {
        foreach ($vars as $name => $val) {
            $string = str_replace("{{{$name}}}", $val, $string);
        }

        return $string;
    }

    /**
     * Secure inputs fields
     *
     * @param string $post
     * @return string
     */
    public function secure(string $post): string
    {
        $post = htmlspecialchars($post, ENT_QUOTES);
        $post = stripslashes($post);
        $post = trim($post);

        return $post;
    }

    /**
     * Error or success message
     *
     * @param string $message
     * @return json
     */
    public function statusHandler(string $message): json
    {
        die(json_encode(self::HANDLER_MSG[$message]));
    }

}

# Instance 
new Ajax_Form();
```

Here's the AjaxForm.js code

```
const publicKey = "XXXXX"; // GOOGLE public key

// Get token from API
function check_grecaptcha() {
    grecaptcha.ready(function () {
        grecaptcha.execute(publicKey, {
            action: "ajaxForm"
        }).then(function (token) {
            $("[name='recaptcha-token']").val(token);
        });
    });
}

// Show response in .alert
function alertShowing(response) {
    $("#response-alert").html(JSON.parse(response));
    $("#response-alert").removeClass("d-none");
    $("#response-alert").addClass("d-block");
}

$(function () {
    check_grecaptcha();
    $("#contactform").validate({
        // Form fields rules
        rules: {
            firstname: {
                required: true,
                minlength: 3
            },
            lastname: {
                required: true,
                minlength: 3
            },
            email: {
                required: true,
                email: true
            },
            message: {
                required: false,
                minlength: 5
            }
        },
        // Error messages
        messages: {
            firstname: {
                required: "Please enter your first name.",
                minlength: "Must be at least 3 characters long."
            },
            lastname: {
                required: "Please enter your last name.",
                minlength: "Must be at least 3 characters long."
            },
            email: "Please enter a valid email.",
            message: {
                required: "Please enter your message.",
                minlength: "Must be at least 5 characters long."
            }
        },
        errorClass: "invalid-feedback",
        // Dynamic validation classes
        highlight: function (element) {
            $(element).addClass("is-invalid").removeClass("is-valid");
        },
        unhighlight: function (element) {
            $(element).addClass("is-valid").removeClass("is-invalid");
        },
        // Action on submit
        submitHandler: function (form) {
            $(".spinner-border").removeClass("d-none");
            $("#sendtext").addClass("d-none");
            $.post(form.action, $(form).serialize())
                .done(function (response) {
                    alertShowing((response));
                    $(".spinner-border").addClass("d-none");
                    $("#sendtext").removeClass("d-none");
                    $("#submit-btn").prop("disabled", true);
                    check_grecaptcha();
                    setTimeout(function () {
                        $("#submit-btn").prop("disabled", false);
                        $("form").trigger("reset");
                        $("form").each(function () {
                            $(this).find(".form-control").removeClass("is-valid")
                        })
                    }, 3000);
                })
                .fail(function (response) {
                    alertShowing((response));
                    $(".spinner-border").addClass("d-none");
                    $("#sendtext").removeClass("d-none");
                });
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Please show the whole content of `AjaxForm.php`

Comment: If the checkbox array is empty, you never set `$instype`.

Comment: There's no `$_POST['instype[]']`. `[]` is removed from the input name when creating the `$_POST` variable. It's `$_POST['instype']`.

Comment: @JimPanse I've edited my post and added the complete AjaxForm.php

Comment: @Barmar I've made that change and now I only get the last item checked on the form and the alert that's to show on the page where the form is located is not appearing (it was previously) :(

Comment: Of course. The code that uses `$instype` should be inside the loop. After the loop it just has the last value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like already stated in the comments. You never initialized your variable `$instype`, but you try to access it several times. At least inititialize the variable **before any access** with an empty value like

```
$instype = ''
```

or by uncommenting

```
$instype = $this->secure($_POST['instype']);
```

But be aware, this won't solve your problem since you have this line in a comment and also will never be run if the the if-condition does not match.

Comment: Thanks. I was able to fix the code properly and will post the answer when I am able to do so (waiting for the 30 minute pause to expire)